# Span around button causing issues

Tags: html, css

I have a span around a button and for some reason the text/button I made is not extending the full width of the container so that it is all on one line. I have tried setting the width to 100% the `like-links-button` as well as the link itself. Nothing seems to work. It works in the snippet, but not on my actual page. Any ideas why not?

```css
#like-links a {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 100%;
}
#like-links-button {
 padding: 15px 20px;
 border: 2px solid #000;
 -webkit-transition: ease-in-out .5s;
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
 color: #000;
}
```

```html
    <div id="like-links"><a href="discuss-project"><span id="like-links-button">DISCUSS DESIGN PROJECT</span></a></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding `display: inline-block` to your span makes it look correct for me.

Answer (score 2):

you need to give a [block formating context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) *(basicly use to deal with float elements)* to your span via `display` for instance. its defaut `display` is `inline` and so, it won't take **vertical** `padding` or `margin` as you would expect.

```css
#like-links a {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 100%;
}
#like-links-button {
 padding: 15px 20px;
 border: 2px solid #000;
 -webkit-transition: ease-in-out .5s;
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
 color: #000;
  display:inline-block;/* make me behave like a box */
}
```

```html
<div id="like-links"><a href="discuss-project"><span id="like-links-button">DISCUSS DESIGN PROJECT</span></a></div>
```